# Insert Row After Specific Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I Want To Use Google Apps Script To Insert One Row After Specific Rows, If The Row In Column C Is "Y" The Script Will Add Row After It

I Tried To Write Code Like This But It Didn't Work

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 function insertRowsAfter() {
   for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i][1] === "Y") {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: This is the illustrative picture]

[This is a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYxN776iMzPu8hMpM0DTetlXS2EQDQCuGz6sOiFe0rw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is in `[1]` as that would be requesting the value for the B Column.

```
if(data[i][1] === "Y") { ...
```

Try adjusting your code to the following to target Column C:

```
if(data[i][2] === "Y") { ...
```

---

Additionally, your `for` loop is only targeting data from the 3rd row onward. I recommend adjusting your code to the following to start in Row 2:

```
for(var i = 1; i < data.length-1; i++) {
```

It's important to know that Arrays are 0-indexed, meaning their first element is at index `0`.

---

Another issue is you are not defining how many rows to insert after the index.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany

```
sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + 1);
```

Should be:

```
sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + 1, 1);
```

---

Another issue is that you must track the amount of new rows you are adding, as we must keep the array of row values accurate. Each time a new row is added, the data becomes offset by 1.

This is solved by adding an offset value:

```
   let offset = 1

   for(let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i][2] === "Y") {
        sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + offset, 1);
        offset += 1;
    }
  }
```

---

Lastly, it's good to practice to avoid naming your functions, variables and beyond as existing functions, classes or methods.

Try renaming your function to something else.

```
function insertNewRow() { ...
```

---

**Result:**

```
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 function insertNewRow() {

   let offset = 1;

   for(let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i][2] === "Y") {
        sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + offset, 1);
        offset += 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i received this error message: 
Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.insertRowsAfter.
insertRowsAfter @ Code.gs:7

Comment: const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 function insertRowsAfter() {
   for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i][2] === "Y") {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + 1, 1);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Looks good, though I don't recommend naming your function identically to the `method` you're using. Try renaming your function `insertRowsAfter` to something else.

Comment: now it's working but added rows in wrong place

Comment: @mergen it's working on my end, is your sheet identical to the screenshot you posted?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYxN776iMzPu8hMpM0DTetlXS2EQDQCuGz6sOiFe0rw/edit#gid=0

Comment: @mergen Updated post, you should be all set!

Comment: THANKS:  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 function addRow() {
 let offset = 1
   for(let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i][2] === "Y") {
        sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + offset, 1);
        offset += 1;
    }
  }
}